# Git solution with multiple projects in C# .NET

Tags: git

I have a Visual Studio solution organized as follows:

```
Solution
  - Company.ProjectName.People
  - Company.ProjectName.Books
  - Company.ProjectName.UI
```

This goes on for something like 20 projects whitin this solution.
Now, physically, these files resides in a structure like that on my pc:

```
C:\dotnetProjects\Company.ProjectName\Company.ProjectName.People
C:\dotnetProjects\Company.ProjectName\Company.ProjectName.Books
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Company.ProjectName.UI
```

Given that structure, how can I instruct Git to track all my projects?
For what I know git is meant to be used within a single folder, where the .git folder resides.

I'd really like my senior web developer to start using Git but I can't propose her to change the whole project structure, and maybe this could also be the correct way to structure it.

In my personal projects I use

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Company.ProjectName (here is the .git folder)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Company.ProjectName\Company.ProjectName.People
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Company.ProjectName\Company.ProjectName.Book
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Company.ProjectName\Company.ProjectName.UI
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Git has a root directory, and tracks anything below that (that you include in your commits). So if you want all these projects in the same Git repository, then put the root directory as the folder that encompasses all your projects.

Comment: If you want to handle your sub-projects as separate repositories, you can do so and organize them in a parent repository as `submodule`s.

Comment: Another idea is to use directory junctions (I think support for it has been improved in the latest Git for Windows versions).

Comment: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Company.ProjectName.UI" Do you really have to place the project in default IIS web site folder?

Comment: @LexLi I don't but my company's projects are structured like so right now and I can't help but use them like so.

Comment: @kowsky I'd like to keep them all in the same repository

Answer (score 0):

I think [NTFS Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) is one of solutions here. You can place UI project in git folder, an create a junction from it to wwwroot.

And just in case - you can easily just create a web site / virtual folder in IIS and map it to any folder, it should not be physically present in wwwroot.